# replace HTML content with multiple elements

Tags: java, html

I have a .html file with a content like that:

```
<ul class="myclass">
  <li>PLACEHOLDER</li>
</ul>
```

I also have an ArrayList like this:

```
["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]
```

Now I want to create a new html file with `li`-entries for all of my elements in this list. So I expect this as a result:

```
<ul class="myclass">
  <li>value 1</li>
  <li>value 2</li>
  <li>value 3</li>
</ul>
```

I could first loop over my List and create a String like `"<li>value 1</li><li>value 2</li><li>value 3</li>"` and do a replace on `"<li>PLACEHOLDER</li>"` - but I hope there is better solution.

Comment: What plataform you are using? Java EE? JSF? What?

Comment: @ Dante Faña Badia: JSE

Comment: Have a look on this using xslt [template](http://javahash.com/transform-xml-with-xstl-using-java/)

Comment: @Munchkin if you are using Java SE the simple solution is what you said replace the string or you can use (or create) a template language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping works fine, but rather than building the entire string then replacing, you can use StringBuilder to concatenate the thing in pieces.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

First add the < ul class="myclass">, then instead of < li>PLACEHOLDER< /li>, loop through your array and append < li>{value}< /li>, etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Java SE the simple solution is what you said replace the string or you can use (or create) a template language Or you can use a existing this is one maked by Apache http://freemarker.org/ (I have never use)